# JQuery else statement after timer

Tags: jquery, timer, if-statement

I have a div I want to fadeOut every hour. But in between hours I want the div to dissapear entirely. I have tried doing that with the following code but do not know why it isnt working:

```
  var now = (new Date()).getTime();
  var lastTime = 0;
  var lastTimeStr = localStorage['lastTime'];
  if (lastTimeStr) lastTime = parseInt(lastTimeStr, 10);
  if (now - lastTime > 1000 *60*60) {
    $('#startup').delay(1500).fadeOut(2000);
  }
  else {
    $('#startup').addClass('nodisplay');
  }

  localStorage['lastTime'] = ""+now;​
```

Currently, everything up to the else statement works fine. I just don't know why it wouldnt be working.

(ps: css .nodisplay just has display:none;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
      $('#startup').show().delay(1500).fadeOut(2000);
}, 1000*60*60);
```

Much simpler method. There is no need for a `'nodisplay'` class, after the fadeOut occurs jQuery uses `display:none` is it will remain hidden after that.

http://jsfiddle.net/T3yqP/1/

Comment: This shows an element for 1.5-3.5 seconds every hour.  Are you sure that's what the OP wanted?

Comment: I may have misunderstood. But thats why I gathered from his question.

Comment: Thanks Fresheyeball but jfriend is right. I want the fadeout animation to occur once every hour, with the element hidden at all other times

Comment: How is that not what I provided? I am confused. It has to be showing for the fade out animation to occur, so my script show it and then fades it out once every hour. It would be hidden all the rest of the time.

Comment: I have added a fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: @MeltingDog - what you have failed to explain is when is the element made visible.  If it fades out every hour, it has to get made visible some time or there's nothing to fade out.

Comment: @jfriend00 So its supposed to show on page load and only be visible for 1 hour?

Comment: @Fresheyeball - I'm waiting for MeltingDog to explain.  They say "fadeout animation occur once every hour", but they don't ever explain how it gets visible so it can fadeOut again or for how long it remains visible.

Comment: Oh gotcha. I will join you in waiting.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys! Much apprecitated. @Fresh - that jfiddle is exactly what I needed - its just playing up on my end. I will have to go back through my css.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Originally I had it in mind that I would display the element using the if statement - IE: if the timer is > then 1 hour run the animation. Else, add the class with display:none. This if and else statment would be run every time the page is visited